# How to use contains(where:) with enumerator Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I can't find a syntax example for contains(where:) with enumerator.

I'm trying to map array 1 and array 2 to see if there is any duplicate and update it. If not append the none duplicate part.

```
struct Info {
    var id: Int
    var info: String
}

var arrayOne: [Info] = [Info(id: 0, info: "I don't like cake"),
                        Info(id: 2, info: "I love soda")]

var arrayTwo: [Info] = [Info(id: 0, info: "I love cake"),
                        Info(id: 1, info: "I love chocolate"),
                        Info(id: 2, info: "I love Milk")]
    
for arr in arrayOne {
   if arrayTwo.enumerated().contains(where: (index, element) in 
//    checking $0.id == arr.id is true
//    then update the array arrayTwo[index] = arr  
   } else {
      arrayTwo.append(arr)
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of your code is legal Swift. I assume you meant this:

```
struct Info {
    var id: Int
    var info: String
}

var arrayOne: [Info] = [Info(id: 0, info: "I don't like cake"),
                        Info(id: 2, info: "I love soda")]

var arrayTwo: [Info] = [Info(id: 0, info: "I love cake"),
                        Info(id: 1, info: "I love chocolate"),
                        Info(id: 2, info: "I love Milk")]
```

Given that, `contains(where:)` is not useful for the problem you're trying to solve. You can't update based only on knowing that the array contains a value; you need to know the actual location of the value. For that you want `firstIndex(where:)`.

```
for arr in arrayOne {
    // Find a matching index
    if let index = arrayTwo.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == arr.id }) {
        // And if it exists, replace it
        arrayTwo[index] = arr
    } else {
        // Otherwise, append
        arrayTwo.append(arr)
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right, I was typing it out blindly and didn't think about it too much. Thanks for pointed out and the answer!

Comment: @14079_Z it might make sense to replace these arrays with dictionaries that key the items by their IDs. After that, this all boils down to just calling a simple [`Dictionary.merge(_:uniquingKeysWith:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127171-merge)